# Android studio is unable to recognize ndk.dir and ANDROID_NDK in Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm running into a strange Android studio problem. My gradle sync fails every time with the following message:

`Error:NDK is not configured. Define location with ndk.dir in local.properties or with an ANDROID_NDK environment variable.`

`local.properties` has been updated through Android studio (I have added the right path to the downloaded NDK in File -> Project structure -> SDK location -> NDK location)

I have also updated my .bash_profile with the ANDROID_NDK environment var and appended it to the PATH.

ANDROID_NDK and ndk.dir point to the same location.

On gradle sync, I still see the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would try wiping the caches. I think the issue could be in either the Android Studio cache or in the Gradle cache, so I would wipe them both.

To clear the Gradle cache:
Locate the folder `.gradle` in your home directory, and delete it.

To clear the Android Studio cache:
In Android Studio, choose `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`. Then choose `Invalidate and Restart` from the pop-up.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache as well. Did not work :/ I posted an answer that fixed the problem. Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. The problem was that Android Studio was auto-generating local.properties in the parent folder as well while importing my project. The local.properties in the parent folder had only the sdk.dir and not the ndk.dir. On adding ndk.dir to that file, I was able to gradle sync successfully.